# CORS issue with Django 4.2 and Next.js frontend using httponly cookies for JWT authentication

Tags: cookies, next.js, django-rest-framework, axios, cors

Hello fellow developers,

I am currently facing a CORS-related problem while trying to set up JWT authentication with Django 4.2 and a Next.js frontend. I'm using Django Rest Framework (DRF) API to serve the frontend app, and Axios to handle API requests from the frontend.

The specific issue I am encountering is related to httponly cookies. I have implemented a mechanism to send JWT authentication tokens as httponly cookies from the backend to the frontend. When inspecting the network requests, I can see that the cookies are being received in the response headers as expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Bt7.png)

However, the problem arises when I try to access the cookies in my Next.js application. The cookies do not seem to be visible or accessible within the application's cookies store. Due to this, I cannot retrieve the authentication tokens from the cookies, which is hindering my authentication process.

I understand that httponly cookies cannot be accessed directly from JavaScript for security reasons, and my intention is not to access them via JavaScript. My goal is to view the httponly cookies in the "Application" or "Storage" section of the Chrome developer tools, just for debugging purposes. However, I cannot find the httponly cookies in the developer tools' application cookie section.

Some additional context:

- Django version: 4.2
- Frontend: Next.js
- Backend API calls: Axios
- Browser: Chrome

DRF api settings:

```py
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + ['set-cookie']

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

NextJS api client:

```js
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
  withCredentials: true
})

const login = () => {
  axiosClient.post('/authsystem/login/', {
    email: "******************",
    password: "*********"
  })
  .then(function(res){
    console.log(res)
  })
}
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem or can offer some insights into this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this CORS-related problem with Django 4.2 and Next.js using httponly cookies for JWT authentication.

I suspect there might be some missing configuration or setting that I am overlooking.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Trying to allow `Set-Cookie` as a request header in your configuration makes no sense, since it's a response header. FYI, attempts to _expose_ that response header [won't work either](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name).

Comment: You're likely running into issues because of `SameSite`. What is the Web origin of your frontend?

Comment: The web origin of my frontend is `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Sorry, I meant backend.

Comment: I'm using 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Couldn't you use `http://localhost:8000` instead. That would make your frontend's and your backend's Web origins _same-site_, which would make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you, that's working just fine. But what should I do if I want to move to production environment where I host my backend API to a server and my frontend to another server ? Or should I host both of them in the same server ? any advice ?

Comment: The easiest thing is to serve under both backend and frontend under the same Web origin, but that's not always possible. Eventually, you'll likely have to properly configure CORS as well as your cookie's `SameSite` (and possibly `Secure) attributes.